# In Vuex, why are the module's state accessed as 'store.state.module' instead of 'store.module.state'?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

In the following code, why is the state of `moduleA` accessed with `store.state.a` instead of `store.a.state`?

Since the `store` holds `moduleA`, and `moduleA` holds its `state`, it makes more sense to me if the `state` of `moduleA` was accessed with `store.a.state`.

```
const moduleA = {
  state: () => ({ ... }),
  ...
}

const moduleB = {
  state: () => ({ ... }),
  ...
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})

store.state.a // -> `moduleA`'s state
store.state.b // -> `moduleB`'s state
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is `store.state.a` instead of `store.a.state` is because there is only one state object in Vuex. Under the hood, all of the modules are combined into a single state object.

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#modules) docs can provide you with additional information.